# Get users from Active Directory by property

Tags: c#, active-directory

How can I get all users filtered by department property?

When I get user by username like `using (var up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, username)) { (...) }` then I can easily get his department:

```cs
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = principal.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
if (directoryEntry.Properties.Contains(property))
{
    return directoryEntry.Properties[property].Value.ToString();
}
```

so I can get department from PrincipalUser. But how get all users with specific department?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalsearcher

Comment: @stuartd how can I filter custom property in```QueryFilter```?